# How to depend one sbt project in some sub level from some lib on root level

Tags: sbt

I have a sbt project structure like this

```
./apps/app1/build.sbt
./apps/app1/src/main/scala/com/abz/app/App1.scala
./apps/app2/build.sbt
./apps/app2/src/main/scala/com/abz/app/App2.scala
./apps/build.sbt
./build.sbt
./core/src/main/scala/com/abz/core/Core.scala
./project
./project/build.properties
./project/plugins.sbt
```

see https://github.com/birkhola/sbt-structure

I want App2 depend on Core (classpath dependency).

It seems to be impossible which I cannot believe given sbt is a quite newly designed tool.

Yes, I know I can put everything in root build.sbt but in bigger projects this quickly gets messy, so I explicitly want to have some structure.

Using sbt 0.13.15 on Ubuntu 16.